# jQuery event firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

If I have a code like the following;

```
if (x == "0")
{
     $("input:checkbox").parent().mouseover(function () {
     //Some code
     }
}
```

My question is will the code get executed on each `mouseover` OR it will first check the `x == "0"` condition and then fire ?

In other words, is the `$("input:checkbox").parent().mouseover()` code similar to what one would get with a `bind()` or `live()` function (which gets fired every time on that event) and the enclosing condition of "x" won't matter ?

Is there any way by which we can link the event with the "x" condition like limiting it's scope only if x is true?

I am not really sure if my question is really valid. But it would be really great if you could clarify.

Comment: depends on how it's being called, but you can unbind it and rebind it if you are worried about mouseover being called all the time.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just reference `x` in the `mouseover` handler? Will `x` be subject to change sometime *after* the `mouseover` handler has been bound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is will the code get executed on each mouseover OR it will
>   first check the x == "0" condition and then fire ?

It'll get executed on each mouseover, if x == "0" at the point you have written this code.

If you want to only execute a piece of code if x == "0", try

```
 var x = "0"; // or any other value.
 $("input:checkbox").parent().mouseover(function () {
   if(x == "0") {
     // code goes here
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

the event will be attached the first time that x has the value = 0. and then it will be executed on each onMousehover, you could detach the event if the x is different to 0.

```
if (x == "0")
{
    $("input:checkbox").parent().mouseover(function () {
    //Some code
} else {
    $("input:checkbox").parent().unbind('mouseover');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once the mouseover event is attached, it will fire regardless of X.  You can get the effect you are looking for by checking X inside the callback function.

```
 var x = 0;

 $("input:checkbox").parent().mouseover(function () {
  if(x != 0) { return; }
  // some code
 }
```

Comment: This requires `x` to have global scope though.